# How to load staring window form in offline mode in a hybrid mobile application

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to hybrid mobile app development. Normally the frontend of my mobile application is developed with ionic, cordova and angular.js and the back end is .net.
This is the scenario I wanted to implement

In my mobile app, when the user is in online mode (with internet connection) the app automatically connect with remote database(host in somewhere else) and load the user templates which is saved in remote database. Actually the templates consists the user window for each type user.For example login widow for adult users,login window for young users, login widow for kids and etc.So then user can select the right template for him/her.
And the next part is the complicated part for me.
When the user in online mode, the app should download all the templates from the remote DB and save it in the local storage od the mobile device.Then when the user launch the app in offline mode(internet connection turned off) again the app should load the templates from the local storage(from the place where the templates are saved in online mode) and then the user can select the window as previously.
Actually this requirement is quite difficult to tackle with for me.So any help in this regards is highly appreciated.I don't have any idea about how to solve this problem.Please help me.Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

1. add connection plugin.
2. write angular wrapper or use ng cordova.
3. write callback function in angualr for information on connection.
   a) in this angualr function change $state to that you need.

Comment: Sorry I am new to hybrid app development..Can you elaborate it further?Any articles or tutorials?Anyway thanking you for your immediate reply.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you create Two global variabel ex. var his = 0; var her = 0; and your select category section if we select his on thai click function his = 1; and onload page function set if condition like if (his == 1) {
    load json throw your his themes.

```
};

**And still you have any confusion then message me.**
```

Comment: My problem is something different.How can I work with remote database in online mode and work with templates downloaded from database in offline mode